# Correct format of JSON data retrieved from server call

Tags: json, meteor, httpresponse

Sorry if this is a stupid question. I am trying to use an API from another project to make some request to a server. The JSON data the server returns have this format: `{ "head": { "link": [], "vars": [ "s", "p", "o" ] },"results": { "distinct": false, "ordered": true, "bindings":` and so on. However when I make the call through my project in meteor the response is like this `"\n{ \"head\": { \"link\": [], \"vars\": [ \"s\", \"p\", \"o\" ] },\n \"results\": { \"distinct\": false, \"ordered\": true, \"bindings\":`
My code looks like this

```
Meteor.call("getURL",'serverURL',{},function(err,res){
    if(err){
      alert('Query not found: '+err);
    }
    if(!err){
      onsole.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    }
}
```

How can I display the response from the server without the \n and \ and so on?

Comment: The response is already a string.  Try `console.log(res)` instead of `console.log(JSON.stringify(res));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because you [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) the result (which is already a string). Try `console.log(res)` only.

Try open up a browser console and type:

```
const x = { "head": { "link": [], "vars": [ "s", "p", "o" ] }}
console.log(JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify(x)));  // same result
```

Comment: Yes, that did the trick. The thing is that just console.log(res) was returning [object Object] i used res.content and worked. Thank you!

Comment: If it worked then you can mark my answer as the correct answer, thanks.

Comment: Btw do you know how I could display each object in different line on the same td cell in html?

Comment: @PetrosM can you be more specific ? And I think that should be a new question.